# Ruby on Rails: Getting Value From Relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a loop to getting values in my database, but when I'm trying to get a value from a relationship, I get an error:

```
undefined method `first_name' for nil:NilClass
```

This is the loop:

```
<%= @sample.each do |s| %>
  <%= s.relation.first_name %>
<% end %>
```

when I tried

```
<%= s.relation.to_json %>
```

with `.to_json`, I get this:

```
{"first_name":"testingtwo","last_name":"fdsaf","updated_at":"2013-11-21T07:47:05Z","user_id":null}
```

Shouldn't `s.relation.first_name` work?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's possible that there is a relation in the loop that *doesn't* have a value, and is getting hung up there - try this:

```
<%= @sample.each do |s| %>
  <%= s.relation.first_name if s.relation %>
<% end %>
```

this only outputs `s.relation.first_name` if it isn't nil.  You could also try this:

```
<%= @sample.each do |s| %>
  <%= s.relation.first_name || "No name given" %>
<% end %>
```

which puts the first name if it exists, or "No name given" if it doesn't

Comment: Thank you! that's what it was!

Answer (score 1):

One important thing you may want to consider too is whether or not having `nil` values within your database for that particular relationship is valid to begin with.

The `||` solution proposed is definitely a good one and a great Ruby pattern, but it may be worth adding in an ActiveRecord validation to ensure your `relation`(ships) are never `nil`.

**[ActiveRecord Validations](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html)** are definitely the way to go in that particular case.